# Well maintained PHP SMTP auth class, without sending an e-mail (Login test)?

Tags: php, smtp, exchange-server, ssl

I want to implement an alternative method for logging in (for @mother_company.xyz type e-mails) and impose it.

The reason is leaving the e-mail provider (in this case Exchange) handle password recovery, password storage to prevent password theft and leave the mail server administrator the job of passing accounts arround (also, mail address owner verification is eliminated and the account can be auto-created on first login).

I have looked at Zend_Mail and Pear Net::SMTP they don't seem to allow just SMTP auth, they require sending an e-mail.

**Does** (preferably standalone, preferably maintained) **a PHP SMTP class exist, which can do all SMTP auth types + all encryption methods** (SSL, TLS, StartTLS, etc.) **and does not require modification for the presented purpose** (it also must return usefull codes to determine if login succeeded or failed)**?**

It would be nice if such a class could autoconfigure the SMTP connection data trough trials (based solely on the domain name), and then return the config for caching/storage.

Comment: Forgot to mention I'm already doing SMTP authentication using a heavily modified/fixed class I found on the internet (I think PHPClasses), for logging in in some admin section for a small website, as an experiment. From this experiment I learned I need a class with quality code and which is easy to configure (or which can auto configure). I'll write it myself if such a thing doesn't exist (go figure, PHP the widest used programming language),  when time allows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is [Swiftmailer](https://github.com/swiftmailer/swiftmailer) mailing tool for php5. It consists of [several components](http://swiftmailer.org/docs/overview.html). One of this components is Swift_SmtpTransport. It extends Swift_Transport_EsmtpTransport that is highly configurable class. U can use start() method of this class just to check if AUTH request was successful

```
require_once("lib/swift_required.php");

$swiftMailerSMTP=Swift_SmtpTransport::newInstance("smtp.gmail.com", 587, "tls")
    ->setUsername("john.doe@domain.tld")
    ->setPassword("iforgotmypassword")
;

//throws Swift_TransportException on auth failure
$swiftMailerSMTP->start();

//end the connection, just in case the current script is going to run for a long while
$swiftMailerSMTP->stop();
$swiftMailerSMTP=null;
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure exactly how you want to handle this. SMTP AUTH is simply a command sent by a mail client to a mail server which authenticates the client against a database of some kind. Im guessing your idea is to somehow have a "fake" php mail client that can go through the motions of authentication, then return with whether the AUTH command was successful.

I can think of ways that MIGHT work, but i dont know of a maintained class, and i doubt you will find one as it is a bit of a "hacky" way of doing things.

If its an exchange your authenticating against, why not use LDAP authentication. Its fairly easy to do, the php LDAP module is maintained for you and your implementing authentication properly (which is always a good thing)

Comment: Well, I'm not saying it will always be Exchange. The software I'm working on can be configured for other companies, which in turn might use something else for a mail server (also, it's not like Exchange will be there forever). I'm not looking for SMTP authorization only class, a class which contains an entire mail package is fine, as long as I can use it for SMTP authorization only, without modification.

Comment: Have a look at the "class.smtp.php" from the phpmailer class. It provides the smtp implementation for phpmailer allowing you to send via external mail servers. It should include Authentication as part of that. Whether its able to "trial" a list of preferred connection types i don't think it can, but its the closest i think your going to get. The rest you will have to custom code

Comment: Looks nice, though it would have been nicer if it had exceptions for error handling right into the SMTP class. It does however have an optional exception error handling mode in the phpmailer class (and seems to meet my requirement of a standalone SMTP class). I will try it tomorow and come back.